# How to check pre created objects in spring

Tags: java, spring

how to check whether @component object is created by ioc before running application? Like can we see in console log or something any other utility that helps to see what all objects are there ready by Spring container before launching application.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logging/console log in the **constructor** of your component
ie:

```
public MyComponent() {
    System.out.println("MyComponent is initializing.............");
    // log.info("MyComponent is initializing.............");
}
```

Actually when you inject by default via `@Autowire`, not specific required=false. If you can start application means that you component already inited successfully otherwise you cannot start application

Comment: I assume that when the OP says "what all objects are there", he's looking for a solution that doesn't involve adding code to each bean class.

Comment: Haha, In case he wanna see all beans which may not be created by him, he can use:
- applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
- actuator https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready
- Using debugger of IDE lol